# Conditionally concatenate strings in R / tidyverse

Tags: r, group-by, concatenation, tidyr, summarize

I have a dataset that is structured like this:

| book | chapter | verse | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | string1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | string2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | string3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | string4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | string5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | string6 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | string7 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | string8 |

And my intended output is:

| book | chapter | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | string1 string2 |
| 1 | 2 | string3 string4 |
| 2 | 1 | string5 string6 |
| 2 | 2 | string7 string8 |

I tried it with the line below, but then it sums up all chapters with the same number regardless of the book number.

`df %>% group_by(chapter) %>% summarise(text = paste(text, collapse=", "))`

I am using tidyr. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use `... %>% group_by(book, chapter) %>% ...`